# Слить два списка

Tags: python

Как слить два списка a b чтобы получить c?

`a = [1,2,6] b = [3,4,5,7,9]`

`с = [1,2,-3,-4,-5,6,-7,-9]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В одну строчку:

```
print(sorted(a + [-x for x in b], key=abs))
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю просто инвертировать все значения списка `b`, объединить списки и отсортировать результат по модулю.

```
a = [1,2,6]
b = [3,4,5,7,9]
c = []

b = list(map(lambda n: -n, b)) # инвертировать
c = sorted(a + b, key=lambda n: abs(n)) # сортировка по модулю

print(c) # [1, 2, -3, -4, -5, 6, -7, -9]
```